# Can we integrate keyboard shortcut in angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm planning to add a shortcut for my website, it's possible that we can integrate a keyboard shortcut like VB.NET?

What should I learn to integrate keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Yes, you can integrate keyboard shortcuts in angularjs

Comment: Do you have any idea? what should I learn in angularjs?

Comment: This is not specific to angularjs, you can do it in vanilla javascript. Refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to angular, it can be done using vanilla javascript. Check if below example helps.

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.key === 's') {
    console.log('Ctrl + s');
    
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Refer **MDN** documentation on [KeyboardEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) to know more about the `event` object and its properties.

Comment: Thanks Master, I will going to test this if its working.